# Remove the Publish metabox for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type for events, and I wish to remove the Publish/Visibility options from the side as they are not relevant to the user.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: *How* are they not relevant?

Comment: it will always be public and has dates the event will occur on set date ranges so no need to change the publish date either.

Answer (score 10):

WordPress provides the [`remove_meta_box()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box) function exactly for this purpose:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', function () {
    remove_meta_box( 'submitdiv', 'events', 'side' );
} );
```

The second parameter, `events`, will need to be replaced with the name of your custom post type.

Comment: I am not looking to remove the entire publish meta box. Only the visibility and the Publish immediately. I wish to keep the publish button and status options.